# Finding Transfer Response

Tags: transfer-function

I'm studying [this](http://www.thegleam.com/ke5fx/gpib/11729c2.pdf) app. note on frequency discrimination method to measure phase noise.

In page 35, appendix A, there are these equations:

[image]

The input to the transfer function is \$\Delta f\$ and output is \$\Delta V\$. What happened to the

\[ 
\sin\left[2 \pi\; f_m \left(t - \frac{\tau_d}{2} \right) \right]
\]

term when writing the equation for delta V?

Sorry if it is too obvious. I just could not see why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of the frequency discriminator is to have some output voltage which depends on the frequency shift \$\Delta f\$. In time domain you have this signal at the output of the discriminator:

\[
V(t) = \Delta V(\Delta f) \cdot 
 \sin\left[2 \pi\; f_m \left(t - \frac{\tau_d}{2} \right) \right]
\]

I.e. you have a sinusoidal signal *whose amplitude* holds the information about the frequency variations of the input. Therefore, in a system perspective, the relationship between your "input" \$\Delta f\$ and the desired output \$\Delta V\$ is independent of the sinusoidal signal time variations.

In other words, by "transfer response" it is meant the relationship between *the amplitude of \$V(t)\$* versus \$\Delta f\$.